# Sort list of dictionary in python based on values and add the sorted objects to a new list

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, numpy

I have a list of dictionary.Each dictionary has two key values which are to be considered while sorting.One is **"col"** and other is **"row"**

**What I want**

For each **"row"** key I want to get all the objects and sort them on the value of **"col"**.And the final list should have all the objects **"row"** wise and sorted on **"col"**

**For example**

For **"row"** key with value 1 I want to get all the objects and  sort those objects in ascending order of value of key **"col".**

Note: value of col ranges from 1 to 12 only

**What I tried**

This is a kind of pseudo-code of what I have tried

```
for column_number in range(1,13):
    for each object in json:
        if object's "row" key is equal to column number(For each coloumn get all of its object):
            add_the_objects_of_each_column_to_a_list
        sort_the_list
        add_the_sorted_list_to_a_new_list(this list should be similar in form as the input)
```

My actual code

```
list_to_sort = []
newlist = []
sorted_list = []


for col_number in range(1,13):
    for obj in mson:    
        if(obj['row'] == col_number):
            list_to_sort.append(obj)
        newlist = sorted(list_to_sort, key=lambda k: k['col'])

#I am not able to write below this for how I will place this sorted newlist in my 

final sorted_list variable which is the final variable I want having row wise objects which are sorted on column
```

The Variable which is to be sorted:

```
mson = [
    {'col': 10, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 3},
    {'col': 1, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
    {'col': 5, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 2, 'size_y': 2},
    {'col': 1, 'row': 3, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
    {'col': 1, 'row': 5, 'size_x': 2, 'size_y': 2},
    {'col': 1, 'row': 7, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
    {'col': 8, 'row': 4, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 3.0},
    {'col': 6, 'row': 7, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2}]
```

**My Desired Output for above variable mson **

```
mson_sorted = [
    {'col': 1, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
    {'col': 5, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 2, 'size_y': 2},
    {'col': 10, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 3},
    {'col': 1, 'row': 3, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
    {'col': 8, 'row': 4, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 3.0},
    {'col': 1, 'row': 5, 'size_x': 2, 'size_y': 2},
    {'col': 1, 'row': 7, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
    {'col': 6, 'row': 7, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2}]
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: I want same variable "mson" but the objects should start from "row" value 1 then row 2 then row 3 etc.For row 1 the objects should be in ascending order of col.For example first it should be row 1 col 1 then row 1 col 3 then row 1 col 8 similarly for row 2 then for row 3 and so on

Comment: @Rookie_123, Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50337132/edit) your question showing us precisely your desired output? You don't have to share you full data set. Do it for a few dictionaries.

Comment: @jpp Sure I will edit it for desired output.And also will remove the extra objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `sorted`

Use the `key` argument in `sorted`.  Make sure to pass a callable that returns a tuple in the elements you want to sort by in the order priority.

```
sorted(mson, key=lambda d: (d['row'], d['col']))

[{'col': 1, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
 {'col': 5, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 2, 'size_y': 2},
 {'col': 10, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 3},
 {'col': 1, 'row': 3, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
 {'col': 8, 'row': 4, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 3.0},
 {'col': 1, 'row': 5, 'size_x': 2, 'size_y': 2},
 {'col': 1, 'row': 7, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
 {'col': 6, 'row': 7, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2}]
```

---

Same answer, more explicit

```
def f(d):
    return d['row'], d['col']

sorted(mson, key=f)
```

---

### Pandas

```
pd.DataFrame(mson, dtype=object).sort_values(['row', 'col']).to_dict('r')

[{'col': 1, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
 {'col': 5, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 2, 'size_y': 2},
 {'col': 10, 'row': 1, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 3},
 {'col': 1, 'row': 3, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
 {'col': 8, 'row': 4, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 3.0},
 {'col': 1, 'row': 5, 'size_x': 2, 'size_y': 2},
 {'col': 1, 'row': 7, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2},
 {'col': 6, 'row': 7, 'size_x': 3, 'size_y': 2}]
```

Comment: This is just awesome.One line solution for it :)

Comment: So the arguments d['row'] d['col'] suggest that first take row then sort on col ?

Comment: Yes.  Also notice that I placed them in a tuple.

Comment: Yeah is it the syntax ?

Comment: When you use the key argument, it needs a function that returns something that can be ordered.  Turns out, tuples can be ordered first by their first elements then by the second and so on.  I used this fact and returned the appropriate thing to get the sort you wanted.